# Postgresql crosstab query generates different result from its component query

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have a table with summaries of trade transactions per product, year and type of transaction. The table has a few million rows. There are 21 distinctive types of transactions and ~20 000 different products. Please see a few exemplary rows below:

```
select * from transactions limit 5;
 tran_type | product |  value  | currency | year | year_product
-----------+---------+---------+----------+------+--------------
 PA        | OKNA    | 1545.27 | PLN      | 2016 | OKNA|2016
 PZ        | ROLKA   | 1701.00 | PLN      | 2016 | ROLKA|2016
 FS        | OKNA    | 1178.86 | PLN      | 2017 | OKNA|2017
 FS        | ALUCYNK | 1485.00 | PLN      | 2015 | ALUCYNK|2015
 FSK       | ALUCYNK | -105.00 | PLN      | 2015 | ALUCYNK|2015
```

Also, I have a small table with all distinctive types of transactions. Since there are 21 different types, it has just 21 rows. Please see a few exemplary rows below:

```
select * from tran_types limit 5;
 tran_type
-----------
 WZE
 WKE
 PWInne
 FZ
 ZS
```

I can compute total value of all transactions within given transaction type by a simple query. Below example for transaction type 'WZE':

```
select sum(value) from transactions where tran_type = 'WZE';
     sum
-------------
 13515564.02
```

Such a query gives proper results, for all types of transactions.
I want to create a table where each year_product would have its own row, while there would be a column with transaction value for each type of transaction. I run following query:

```
create table cross_view 
as select * from crosstab
    ('select 
        year_product, tran_type, value from transactions order by 1', 
     'select 
        tran_type from tran_types') 
as 
    (year_product text, 
     wze numeric(12,2), 
     wke numeric(12,2), 
     pw_other numeric(12,2), 
     fz numeric(12,2), 
     zs numeric(12,2), 
     mmp numeric(12,2), 
     pzi numeric(12,2), 
     wzk numeric(12,2), 
     fs numeric(12,2), 
     zz numeric(12,2), 
     rw_prod numeric(12,2), 
     mmw numeric(12,2), 
     pak numeric(12,2), 
     pw_prod numeric(12,2), 
     rw_other numeric(12,2), 
     pz numeric(12,2), 
     wz numeric(12,2), 
     pa numeric(12,2), 
     pzk numeric(12,2), 
     pwk_other numeric(12,2), 
     fsk numeric(12,2));
```

where wze, wke, ..., fsk are distinctive transaction types.

Resulting table looks as I expected. Please find a few exemplary rows below:

```
select * from cross_view limit 3;
 year_product | wze | wke | pw_other | fz |    zs    |   mmp   | pzi | wzk |   fs    | zz | rw_prod |   mmw   | pak | pw_prod | rw_other |   pz    |   wz    |   pa    | pzk | pwk_other |   fsk
--------------+-----+-----+---------+----+----------+---------+-----+-----+---------+----+---------+---------+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----+----------+---------
 ALUCYNK|2015 |     |     |         |    |  5447.50 | 1049.45 |     |     | 1485.00 |    |         | 1049.38 |     |         |         | 9613.05 | 8840.50 |  646.21 |     |          | -105.00
 ALUCYNK|2016 |     |     |         |    | 11807.30 |         |     |     |  671.05 |    |         |         |     |         |   30.62 | 9334.53 | 9510.25 | 2617.78 |     |          |
 ALUCYNK|2017 |     |     |         |    |   798.85 | 1999.28 |     |     |  945.00 |    |         | 1999.28 |     |         |         | 2686.08 | 1954.00 |  146.85 |     |          |
```

Again, I can compute total value of all transactions within given transaction type by a simple query. Below example for transaction type 'WZE':

```
select sum(wze) from cross_view;
    sum
------------
 8222568.52
```

For 18 types of transaction, I get 100% correct figure. 
However, for other 3 types, the figure is completely off. One of such transaction types is 'WZE'. As you could see, the result of query on 'transactions' table has been very different from query on 'cross_view' table.

I have no idea where such discrepancy can come from.
I tried changing data types - no improvement.
I reviewed dozens of transactions - there seems to be no apparent difference between 'WZE' transactions and any other type. No 'null' values, empty records, odd formatting etc.
I created a new table with just a first component of 'crosstab' query:

```
create table test as select year_product, tran_type, value from transactions order by 1
```

It gives proper values of transactions.  Therefore, there seems to be no apparent mistake with query used for creating 'cross-view' table.

Do you have any idea where this problem comes from?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the counts matching for WZE in `transactions` and `cross_view`?

Comment: Are there NULL values in *year_product* field?

Comment: @ jusermar10 actually, no... there seems to be ~30% more 'WZE' rows in 'transactions' compared to 'cross_view'.

Comment: @ Parfait - no, there are no NULL values.

Comment: Did you find the reason of the discrepancy? I am with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did.
I had to add coherent sorting of "tran_type":

```sql
create table cross_view 
as select * from crosstab
    ('select 
        year_product, tran_type, value from transactions order by 1' **asc**, 
     'select 
        tran_type from tran_types' **order by tran_type asc**) 
as 
   **year_product, tran_type, value**
```

I have marked in bold what I have changed from the initial version.